# Cannot Iterate Through 2D List

Tags: java, list, arraylist

Okay, so I have my for loop here ...

```
    System.out.println(positions.get(0)[0]);
    for (int x = 0; x < positions.size(); x++) {
        System.out.println("Spawning monsters! Current level is " + level);
        getMap().spawnMonsterOnGroudBelow(mobs.get(level), positions.get(x)[0], positions.get(x)[1]);
    }
```

It contains an int list inside, but for some reason it stops iterating on the first go around. The size of positions is **10**, so I know for a fact that it should iterate 10 things, but on my console it only prints one time when it should print 10 times.

When I printed the 2d list itself, I got this ...

```
[[object array], [object array], [object array] ....]
```

I can't access any of the elements in each of the arrays, but I know the arrays exist. So my question is: how come I can't access the elements in each of those arrays? My code just stops the moment I try to.

Comment: Print positions.size() before you start the loop. If it only runs once, either the positions.size() is 1 or an exception is thrown in the loop (assuming you do not have another thread running that's modifying the array).

Comment: It stops because an exception is thrown? What does your output show? Show the exact type of positions, and show the method signature for spawnMonsterOnGroudBelow(...), means what are the parameter types.

Comment: No output is shown in my console. It just doesn't print.

Comment: Does it print nothing at all? or does it print, but nothing from the loop? Also, are errors showing in your console window? (some IDE's have options to hide them)

Comment: The only other explanation is that `spawnMonsterOnGroudBelow` takes too long / is an endless loop.

Comment: It just doesn't print. It doesn't print the statement above the forloop, nor does it print the statement inside it.

Comment: Ok - then it simply means that this piece of code is never executed ... You expect it to reach there - but it never does.

Comment: What IDE are you using? If System.out.println("test"); doesn't show, the loop isn't your problem.

Comment: Except the print does work for any other case. It just stops printing when I call the index in the list.

Comment: What does (positions == null) return? If it's false, then what does positions.size() return?

Comment: Ok then you might get an Exception or catch an Exception and System.exit() when it happens... which would explain it, System.out.println() is not written immediately, so it might still fail after it I think... or at least errors can occur before them when they happened after them.

Comment: So far ... either it simply never reaches the code, and/or `positions==null`. `positions==null` would generate an exception during the first println ... so if nothing is in the output, that might mean this Exception is caught and handled. Either way - with information given, there is no way to make a final determination.

Comment: I think at this point the guys who noted that it throws an exception are correct because positions is never null. It works the moment I change the 2d array to a 1d array, so I'm guessing there was an issue with me reading through the 2d array.